# Username is just email on Windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, microsoft-account, username

When I created my account on my computer, I chose to link it to my Microsoft account. My username (user directory name, other stuff too) is `#####_000` where `#####` is the first five letters of my email address.

This has only been mildly annoying until recently when I got into Rainmeter and all the account widgets say "Hello, #####_000!" rather than "Hello, [my actual name]!"

Is there a way for me to fix this?

Comment: Rainmeter is pretty configurable. Can't you edit it there?

Comment: @LPChip Technically I could, but that doesn't change the fact that any other program that looks wherever you look to find the username will find #####_000.

Comment: I know. Thats why I didn't post this as an answer. Just in case it seems impossible.